# Extract multiple dataframes from dictionary with Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm using the pandas library in Python.

I've taken an excel file and stored the contents in a data frame by doing the following:

```
path = r"filepath"
sheets_dict = pd.read_excel(path,sheet_name=None)
```

As there was multiple sheets, each containing a table of data with identical columns, I used pd.read_excel(path,sheet_name=None). This stored all the individual sheets into a dictionary with the key for each value/sheet being the sheet name.

I now what to unpack the dictionary and place each sheet into a single data frame. I want to use the key of each sheet in the dictionary as either part of a mulitindex so I know what key/sheet of each table came from or appended as a new column which gives me the key/sheet name for each unique subset of the dataframe.

I've tried the following:

```
for k,df in sheets_dict.items():
    df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df)])
    df['extract'] = k
```

However I'm not getting the results I want.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `keys` argument in `pd.concat` which will set the keys of your dict as the index.

```
df = pd.concat(sheets_dict.values(),keys=sheets_dict.keys())
```

by default, `pd.concat(sheet_dict)` will set the indices as the keys.